# USB dongle for bluetooth keyboard with keyboard driver

Tags: usb, keyboards, bluetooth

I’m looking for device that will allow to connect my Bluetooth keyboard to any computer – it should be like a bridge between keyboard and send keyboard keys via USB so no driver is needed. On receiver side it should be tread like normal USB keyboard. 
I need this for sharing my keyboard via KVM to connected PC’s. Is there any device like that on the market?

Comment: That seems overly complicated compared to just using a wireless USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

orico bta-403 https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=orico+bta-403&_sacat=0

Asus USB-BT400 https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=Asus+BT400&_sacat=0

Bluetooth USB Adapter 4.0 Wireless Adapter for Laptop PC Support Mouse Keyboard https://www.gearbest.com/chargers-cables/pp_1710743.html

How each one works in your particular case - no one can say. You just have to try.

Comment: As far as I know those are standard Bluetooth dongles but they have to be installed on device – when you connect it to KVM it is not visible and you don’t have an option to pair. I need some device that will handle Bluetooth inside and will be visible as HID device. I found this but it is little expensive:

https://shop.intelletto.com/products/bk100

Comment: May be. I do not argue. In any case, you just have to try.

Comment: Found https://allinthehead.com/retro/170/bluetooth-kvm  "I just set up a Logitech MX 5000 Wireless Bluetooth keyboard with a Belkin F1DS102U KVM switch. It works great. I just plugged the bluetooth usb interface that comes with the keyboard into one of the usb device ports on the KVM switch. Works like a charm except this switch cannot use the hot-keys to switch between ports, so i have to get up and walk over to the switch every time I want to change ports."

Comment: Than you for your time but you are missing a point here. You have used usb dongle that comes with keyboard and it is already paired (I don’t event know if it is using Bluetooth). I also have mouse with dongle that is working with KVM but the problem is with devices that use Bluetooth. To connect that king of device your host should have Bluetooth receiver, if not you can use usb dongle that provides bluetooth but those devices are directed from host so driver is needed and most important you are initiating pairing from host.